# How do I install grub?

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu and I am getting an error message of unable to install grub in dev sda. Then a dialogue box popped up that reads:

Sorry, an error occurred and it is not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location.

How would you like to proceed?

Choose a different device to install the bootloader on:

Continue without a boot loader.

Cancel the installation.

Ubuntu works off the disk but I keep getting the same error when I try to install it. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the disk for defects ?

Answer (score 1):

I know one can only install linux in a different device from where it is being run the instalation-live-cd

If you are using the ubuntu cd/dvd, and trying to install to a hard-drive, you should have no problem

However, if you are using ubuntu from a usb-drive, and try to install it into another partition of the same usb-drive, then the installer will not be able to install grub because it cannot write the partition table (for the boot-loader)

Hope it helps

PD: it could help diagnose the problem if you posted the devices and partitions where you want to install ubuntu (as seen in the installation process)

Comment: I don't really know what I am doing.  I just want to put ubuntu on an old computer to test it out before putting it on my other computer.  I made the cd and tried to install it but I keep getting that error.  If I try to change the partitions then it tells me there is no root location.

Comment: I don't know, but nonetheless check the cd for defects (google for instructions it's as easy as installing a prog and running it against the md5 and iso files) as pointed by bodhi.zazen, sometime it happened to me that the iso file downloaded was not ok and the installation would not work because of that.